# Python not fully decompressing snappy parquet

Tags: python, apache-spark, parquet, snappy

I'm importing parquet snappy files using the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob('/home/....101.parquet/*.parquet')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_parquet(fp) for fp in files])
```

The final result that I am showing in the picture is not fully decompressed.

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 1):

The data is fully decompressed, but some columns are [struct types](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.struct.html#pyarrow.struct).

You can try flattening them by calling this:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

pd.concat([pq.read_table(fp).flatten().to_pandas() for fp in files])
```

But I'm not sure it will fully help because it looks like some of them contain arrays.

Comment: No it daoes not make any difference. But thank you I think I'm getting closer